# Any way to determine via AWS API whether EC2 instance uses instance stores?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

So, I manage a large fleet of EC2 instances, and some of them have [instance store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) data volumes (i.e. not the root volume). I want to find all the environments which use this type of storage, but neither [`describe-instances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) nor [`describe-instance-attribute`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-attribute.html) (with the `blockDeviceMapping` attribute) seem to tell me. In other words, instances which I *know* use instance storage (by checking `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/` from the instance itself as per [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html)), don't have those volumes show up in the volume list for the regular AWS API call.

Are there any API calls I can use external to the instance to determine whether the instance was launched with instance store volumes, or will I have to run commands on the instances every time?

Really hope I'm just missing something obvious. :P

Comment: I guess you can get AMI ID and then run `describe-images` to get info about ephemeral storage.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev the AMI instance store setting can be overridden when the instance is actually launched.

Comment: *sigh* To the jackass who decided this was worth downvoting, not that you'll read this, but... In what way is this a bad question? It's not uncommon for hosts to become unreachable, nor is it inconceivable that there will be a host a person cannot access but may wish to stop, and it's uncharacteristically unhelpful of AWS to not provide this information somewhere via an API available from somewhere *other* than the instance itself. I did research, and this is a question the answer to this question was important to the development I was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are missing anything obvious.  The documentation only mentions using instance metadata.

> When you view the block device mapping for your instance, you can see only the EBS volumes, not the instance store volumes. You can use instance metadata to query the complete block device mapping.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html

Comment: Note, however, that the instance store could be attached but not actually "used," so it really depends on why you want to know.  My standard practice is to always attach it even if I don't need it.  It seems 
bit ridiculous not to, since you can't go back and add it later.  Thus, I can always tell whether an instance has instance store volumes by the instance type alone.